# Recommended way to run commands after installing dependencies in the virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, tox

I would like to use *tox* to run *py.test* on a project which needs additional setup in addition to installing packages into the virtualenv. After creating the virtualenv and installing dependencies, some commands need to be run.

Specifically I'm talking about setting up a *node* and *npm* environment using [nodeenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv):

```
nodeenv --prebuilt -p
```

I see that tox allows me to provide a custom command used for installing dependencies by setting [`install_command`](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-install_command=ARGV) in `tox.ini`. But I don't think this is what I want because that *replaces* the command (I assume `pip`) used to install dependencies.

I thought about using a py.test fixture with *session* scope to handle setting up nodeenv but that seems hacky to me as I don't want this to happen when py.test is run directly, not via tox.

What is the least insane way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all necessary setup after the creation of the virtualenv and the dependency installation in [commands](http://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html?highlight=commands#confval-commands=ARGVLIST). Yes, it says "the commands to be called for testing." but if you need to do extra work to prepare for testing you can just do it right there.

It works through whatever you throw at it in the order it is given - e.g.:

```
  [testenv:someenv]
  deps = 
    nodeenv
    pytest
    flexmock
  commands =
     nodeenv --prebuilt -p
     ; ... and whatever else you might need to do
     py.test path/to/my/tests
```

If you have commands/scripts or whatever else that produces the right result but it returns a non zero exit status you can ignore that by prepending `-` (as in `- naughty-command`).

If you need more steps to happen you can wrap them in a little (Python) script and call that script instead as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834447/2626627.

There is also an issue to add the ability to use more than one install command: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/715 is implemented.

Comment: Seems to be the best way available. I will just have to check whether the command has already been called an not call it again on later test runs.

Comment: This answer is okay, but it also misses the mark. I wish to do the same thing - install node and its dependencies in an install step, separate from the step in which the tests run. This recommendation will not work, for example, when one runs `pytest --notest` - it will install the Python environment but not the node environment. Probably, tox should present `install_commands` instead of simply `install_command`, much the same way that CI environments have install steps that precede test steps.

Comment: I note that instead of whitelisting nodeenv, you could invoke nodeenv through python with `python -m nodeenv --prebuilt -p`.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs you can do this: `tox -r -- -k whatever` assuming that you dont have a test with 'whatever" in its name :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and as it was important for me to be able to create the environment without invoking the tests (via `--notest`), I wanted the install to happen in the install phase and not the run phase, so I did something slightly differently. First, I created a `create-env` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

pip install $@
nodeenv --prebuilt --python-virtualenv --node=8.2.1
```

Made it executable, Then in tox.ini:

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
install_command = ./create-env {opts} {packages}
deps = nodeenv
commands = node --version
```

This complete example runs and outputs the following:

```
$ tox
python create: .../.tox/python
python installdeps: nodeenv
python installed: nodeenv==1.3.0
python runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='1150209523'
python runtests: commands[0] | node --version
v8.2.1
_____________________________________________________________________ summary ______________________________________________________________________
  python: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

This approach has the downside that it would only work on Unix.

In [tox 715](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/715), I propose the possibility of native support for multiple install commands.

Comment: doest this work? IMHO it would result in `tox.ConfigError: ConfigError: 'install_command' must contain '{packages}' substitution`

Comment: for more complex tox.ini (eg. custom index server) it will also not work, as it will only pass 2 arguments. IMHO `$@` is a better choice here than `$1 $2`

Comment: Good catch. I've refined the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: got another one: it's a good idea to add `set -e`  at the beginning, because without it if any command does not succed, it is not propagated to tox, and it does'nt know that something went wrong ;)